# Firebase Analytics - file:// based environment support

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-analytics, kaios

I am developing an app for KaiOS, a fork of the old Firefox OS, for which apps are based on HTML5 + JS. When compiling and running on device, Firebase analytics stops working. I receive an error as follows. I believe the issue is due to the fact that on device the app is served in the browser via a file:// based URL scheme rather than a http:// based scheme.

> @firebase/analytics:  DOMException: A request was placed against a
>   transaction which is currently not active, or which is finished.

In my research, I have found that Cordova, Expo, and other file:// based environments have had issues around the use of IndexDB not being supported, which FA relies on. I can confirm that KaiOS does have full support for IndexDB, however the above issue persists. Anyone have any experience getting FA to work in this type of environment?

**Relevant Code:**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen(screenName);

firebase.analytics().logEvent("screen_view", {
    app_name: this.AppName,
    screen_name: screenName,
    app_version: this.AppVersion
});
```